# Move player on big canvas javascript game

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas, game-engine

I wrote this code. This is simple game engine. 
A few things are still missing (collisions, sounds, text descriptions), but this is only the beginning :-)
The player can be controlled using the arrows.
But I have 2 problems. Maybe someone will tell me something how to do it.

1. Moving the player
   now when the player is moving the screen moves at a different pace.
   The effect is that after a short time the player is obscured by the edge of the screen.

I suspect the problem lies somewhere here:
    ctx.translate(player.x, player.y);
but I have no idea what I wrote wrong in this code.

2. Camera View
   By default, the canvas will be very large, up to 10,000 x 10,000 points. Several hundred paths and rooms (green and sand rectangles) will be drawn on the canvas.
   I suppose whole canvas is rendered at the moment, even the off-screen part.
   And this is probably a considerable waste of computer resources.
   But I have no idea how to do it.

Of course, if there is anything else to improve here, I will gratefully accept any suggestions.

```js
window.addEventListener('load', function(event) {
  initCanvas();
});



let ctx;
let cW = 3000; // canvas width
let cH = 3000; // canvas height
let playerImgTop;
let playerImgBottom;
let playerImgLeft;
let playerImgRight;
let playerSpeed = 20;
let playerDir = 0;



function initCanvas() {
  ctx = document.getElementById('mycanvas').getContext('2d');
  ctx.canvas.width = cW;
  ctx.canvas.height = cH;
  let animateInterval = setInterval(render, 1000/30);

  playerImgTop = new Image();
  playerImgTop.src = "http://www.itbvega.pl/io/img/player-top.png";
  playerImgBottom = new Image();
  playerImgBottom.src = "http://www.itbvega.pl/io/img/player-bottom.png";
  playerImgLeft = new Image();
  playerImgLeft.src = "http://www.itbvega.pl/io/img/player-left.png";
  playerImgRight = new Image();
  playerImgRight.src = "http://www.itbvega.pl/io/img/player-right.png";

  let gameLocations = [
      {"id": "room0", "x": 180, "y": 180, "rw": 60, "rh": 60, "type": "room"},
      {"id": "room1", "x": 160, "y": 380, "rw": 100, "rh": 100, "type": "room"},
      {"id": "path0", "x": 200, "y": 240, "rw": 20, "rh": 140, "type": "path"}
  ];

  function renderGameLocations() {
    for (let i = 0; i < gameLocations.length; i++) {
      let loc = gameLocations[i];
      if (loc.type === "path") {
        ctx.fillStyle = "#62d299";
      } else if (loc.type === "room") {
        ctx.fillStyle = "#e4b65e";
      }
      ctx.fillRect(loc.x, loc.y, loc.rw, loc.rh);

    }
  }


  function render() {
    ctx.save();
    ctx.clearRect(0,0, cW, cH);

    renderGameLocations();

    player.render();

    ctx.translate(player.x, player.y);

    ctx.restore();
  }
}



function Player() {
  this.x = 200;
  this.y = 200;
  this.render = function() {
    if (playerDir === 0) {
      ctx.drawImage(playerImgTop, this.x, this.y);
    } else if (playerDir === 1) {
      ctx.drawImage(playerImgRight, this.x, this.y);
    } else if (playerDir === 2) {
      ctx.drawImage(playerImgBottom, this.x, this.y);
    } else if (playerDir === 3) {
      ctx.drawImage(playerImgLeft, this.x, this.y);
    }
  }
}

let player = new Player();


document.addEventListener('keydown', function(event) {
  let key_press = event.keyCode;
   //alert(event.keyCode + " | " + key_press);
  if (key_press === 38 ) { // top
    player.y -= playerSpeed;
    playerDir = 0;
  } else if (key_press === 40) { // bottom
    player.y += playerSpeed;
    playerDir = 2;
  } else if (key_press === 37) { // left
    player.x -= playerSpeed;
    playerDir = 3;
  } else if (key_press === 39) { // right
    player.x += playerSpeed;
    playerDir = 1;
  }
});
```

```html
<canvas id="mycanvas"></canvas>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your question covers a lot of ground way too much for a detailed answer. I have split it into two topics, *the playfield and view* and the *Quad trees* that will briefly cover the two questions you have.

I have added an example that implements both subject at the most basic level. Use the example to explore the finer details. If you have questions, ask in the comments or as new SO questions.

### The playfield and the view

The playfield is the whole map. (see example `playfield`)
It does not contain pixels, it only contains items to display and interact with. (see example `playfield.quadMap` `playfield.visibleItems` and `mapItems`)

The view is the canvas.

It is not larger than the display and contains only pixels.

The view is independent of the playfield and can be positioned, rotated and scaled. The example only positions the view.

The view is set relative to something of interest in the playfield. For example the player. (see example `playfield.setView`)

You set the view (`top` `left`) by taking the players position and subtracting half the views width and height.

To ensure that the view does not go outside the playfield you check that top left is not less than 0 and top left plus view width and height is not greater than playfield width and height. (see example `playfield.setView`)

To use the view you set the canvas transform so that the origin is `-top` and `-left` and then draw items at there normal position.

### Quad trees

When you have a large playfield with many items it can be way to much work for the device to draw all items. Even items off the view will chew a little CPU time that mounts up and makes the game very slow.

To improve performance you need only draw (and update) items that are visible. However the process of finding visible items can add as much load as just calling the draw functions. You need to use a method that can quickly find visible items without needing to test every item in the playfield.

In 2D this can be done using a special type of linked list called a quad tree.

- A quad tree is made up of squares. Each square has a x,y position and a width and height. In example `Quad`
- The first quad is the same size as the playfield. In example it is 16000 pixels square.
- Each quad can also have 4 sub quads that represent the quad divided in 4. See example `Quad.prototype.divide`
- You repeat for each subQuad, give each 4 more sub quads. You set a max depth, that is the number of time you divide sub Quads into more sub Quads. (in the example the `maxDepth` is 5)
- The smallest quad in the example is thus the playfield `size / (2 ** maxDepth) === 16000 / 32 === 500` meaning it covers 500 by 500 pixels of the playfield.
- At the bottom of the quad tree you store the items that overlap that quad. An item may overlap several quads, each quad that item overlaps must contain that item. (in example an item is just a rectangle with a `x`,`y`, `w`, `h` and `col`or)
- You can test if any quad overlaps the current view. See example (`Quad.prototype.isInView`) If it does not then it and all its sub quads and the items they contain are not visible. This very quickly eliminates the need to check up to 3/4 of the items.

The playfield object contains the top most `Quad`. When you set the view `playfield.setView` it builds the view transform and creates a map of all items in all the visible quads. When `setView` returns the map `playfield.visibleItem` contains all items that are in quads that overlap the view.

As map items can be in several quads at the same time you need to quickly build a list of items without repeating the same item. You can do this with a [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) or [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) (these are build in JavaScript objects) and avoids the need to check if an item is already in the list.

### Example

Use **ARROW** keys to move. You must **click canvas** to start as SO snippets will not auto focus the keyboard.

The map `playfield` is very large 16,000 by 16,000 pixels, and there are 10,000 items in the map.

Using quad tree to find visible items makes it possible to animate the view in real-time at 60FPS.

```js
const keys = { // keys to listen to
    ArrowUp: false,
    ArrowLeft: false,
    ArrowRight: false,
    ArrowDown: false,
};
document.addEventListener('keydown', keyEvent);
document.addEventListener('keyup', keyEvent);  
document.addEventListener("click",()=>requestAnimationFrame(mainLoop),{once:true});
var startTime;
var globalTime;
const mapItemCount = 10000;
const maxItemSize = 120; // in pixels
const minItemSize = 20; // in pixels
const maxQuadDepth = 5;
const playfieldSize = 16000; // in pixels
var id = 1;  // unique ids for map items
const mapItems = new Map();  // unique map items
const directions = {
    NONE: {idx: 0, vec: {x: 0, y: 0}},
    UP: {idx: 3, vec: {x: 0, y: -1}},
    RIGHT: {idx: 0, vec: {x: 1, y: 0}},
    DOWN: {idx: 1, vec: {x: 0, y: 1}},
    LEFT: {idx: 2, vec: {x: -1, y: 0}},
};
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

function mainLoop(time) {
    if(!startTime) { startTime = time }
    globalTime = time - startTime;
    playfield.sizeCanvas();
    ctx.setTransform(1,0,0,1,0,0);
    ctx.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
    
    player.update();
    playfield.setView(player);  // current transform set to view
    
    playfield.drawVisible();
    player.draw();
    
    info.textContent = `Player: X:${player.x|0} Y${player.y|0}: , View Left:${playfield.left | 0} Top:${playfield.top | 0} , visibleItems: ${playfield.visibleItems.size} of ${mapItems.size}`;
    
    requestAnimationFrame(mainLoop);
}

function Quad(x, y, w, h, depth = maxQuadDepth) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.w = w;
    this.h = h;
    if (depth > 0) { this.divide(depth) }
    else { this.items = [] }
}
Quad.prototype = {
    divide(depth) {
        this.subQuads = [];
        this.subQuads.push(new Quad(this.x, this.y, this.w / 2, this.h / 2, depth - 1));
        this.subQuads.push(new Quad(this.x + this.w / 2, this.y, this.w / 2, this.h / 2, depth - 1));
        this.subQuads.push(new Quad(this.x + this.w / 2, this.y + this.h / 2, this.w / 2, this.h / 2, depth - 1));
        this.subQuads.push(new Quad(this.x, this.y + this.h / 2, this.w / 2, this.h / 2, depth - 1));       
    },
    isInView(pf) {  // pf is playfield
        return !(this.x > pf.left + pf.cWidth || this.x + this.w < pf.left || this.y > pf.top + pf.cHeight || this.y + this.h < pf.top);
    },
    addItem(item) {
        if (!(item.x > this.x + this.w || item.x + item.w < this.x || item.y > this.y + this.h || item.y + item.h < this.y)) {
            if (this.subQuads) {
                for (const quad of this.subQuads) { quad.addItem(item) }
            } else { this.items.push(item.id) }
        }
    },
    getVisibleItems(pf, itemMap, items = new Map()) {
        if (this.subQuads) {
            for (const quad of this.subQuads) {
                if (quad.isInView(pf)) { quad.getVisibleItems(pf, itemMap, items) }
            }
        } else {
            for (const id of this.items) { items.set(id, itemMap.get(id)) }
        }
        return items
    }   
}
// only one instance then define as object
const playfield = {
    width: playfieldSize,
    height: playfieldSize,
    view: [1,0,0,1,0,0],  // view as transformation matrix
    cWidth: 0,  // canvas size
    cHeight: 0, // canvas size
    top: 0,
    left: 0,
    sizeCanvas() {
        if(canvas.width !== innerWidth || canvas.height !== innerHeight) {
            this.cWidth = canvas.width = innerWidth;
            this.cHeight = canvas.height = innerHeight;         
        }
    },
    setView(player) {
        var left = player.x - this.cWidth / 2;
        var top = player.y - this.cHeight / 2;
        left = left < 0 ? 0 : left > this.width - this.cWidth ? this.width - this.cWidth : left;
        top = top < 0 ? 0 : top > this.height - this.cHeight ? this.height - this.cHeight : top;
        this.view[4] = -(this.left = left);
        this.view[5] = -(this.top = top);
        ctx.setTransform(...this.view);
        this.visibleItems.clear();
        this.quadMap.getVisibleItems(this, mapItems, this.visibleItems);
    },
    drawVisible() {
        for(const item of this.visibleItems.values()) { item.draw() }  
    },
    quadMap: new Quad(0, 0, playfieldSize, playfieldSize),
    visibleItems: new Map(),
}

function MapItem(x, y, w, h, col = "#ABC") {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.w = w;
    this.h = h;
    this.col = "#ABC";
    this.id = id++;
    mapItems.set(this.id,this);
    playfield.quadMap.addItem(this);
}
MapItem.prototype = {
    draw() {
        ctx.fillStyle = this.col;
        ctx.fillRect(this.x, this.y, this.w, this.h);
    }
}
addMapItems(mapItemCount)
function addMapItems(count) {
    while (count-- > 0) {
        const x = Math.random() * playfield.width;
        const y = Math.random() * playfield.height;
        const w = Math.random() * (maxItemSize - minItemSize) + minItemSize;
        const h = Math.random() * (maxItemSize - minItemSize) + minItemSize;
        const item = new MapItem(x,y,w,h);
    }
}

// only one instance then define as object
const player = {
    x: 1200,
    y: 1200,
    speed: 10,
    image: undefined,
    direction: undefined,
    draw() {
        ctx.fillStyle = "#F00";
        ctx.save();  // need to save and restore as I use rotate to change the current transform that 
                     // holds the current playfield view.
        const x = this.x;
        const y = this.y;
        ctx.transform(1,0,0,1,x,y);
        ctx.rotate(this.direction.idx / 2 * Math.PI);
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.lineTo(20, 0);
        ctx.lineTo(-10, 14);
        ctx.lineTo(-10, -14);
        ctx.fill();
        ctx.restore();
        
    },
    update() {
        var dir = directions.NONE;
        if (keys.ArrowUp) { dir = directions.UP }
        if (keys.ArrowDown) { dir = directions.DOWN }
        if (keys.ArrowLeft) { dir = directions.LEFT }
        if (keys.ArrowRight) { dir = directions.RIGHT }
        this.x += dir.vec.x * this.speed;
        this.y += dir.vec.y * this.speed;
        this.x = this.x < 0 ? 0 : this.x > playfield.width ? playfield.width : this.x;
        this.y = this.y < 0 ? 0 : this.y > playfield.height ? playfield.height : this.y;
        this.direction = dir;
        
    }
};


function keyEvent(e) {
    if (keys[e.code] !== undefined) {
        keys[e.code] = e.type === "keydown";
        e.preventDefault();
    }
}
```

```css
canvas {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
}
#info {
    font-family: arial;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    font-size: small;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
<div id="info">Click to start</div>
```

Comment: 15 minutes I raised my jaw from the floor.
Probably because my brain was frozen after looking at the code ;-)
Your code is awesome!
Unfortunately, I'm a beginner in programming and I do everything very simply.
Even if someone wakes me up in the middle of the night, I'm able to quickly explain my code :)
Many thanks for such an extensive piece of code with great explanations!
I will have to disarm this code for many days to understand how these mechanisms work and how to use them.
Thanks again!